# generating templates with grunt - looking for a task

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, gruntjs, task

I've got an HTML file with following content:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span>{{ secret }}</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for a grunt task that could take this source file, take a map of values:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  myTask: {
    myTarget: {
      src: ...
      dest: ...
      values: {
        secret: 'ABC'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and generate output file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span>ABC</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any task like this? I saw [grunt-mustache-html](https://github.com/haio/grunt-mustache-html) but it forces lots of things to exist which I really don't need and I don't want to use it. I want simply to take a single mustache (or hbs or whatever), fill it with data from grunt-level object and dump the result into another HTML file, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [grunt-template](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) which processed [lo-dash templates](https://lodash.com/docs/#template). Here's a basic setup to solve your problem:

```
//Gruntfile.js
config.template = {
    myTask: {
        options: {
            data: function () {
                return {
                    secret: 'ABC' 
                };
            }
        },
        files: {
            'output.html: ['template.html.tpl']
        }
    }
};

//template.html.tpl
<html>
   <body>
      <span><%= secret %></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**#1**. One options is to make use of [`grunt.template`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) utility (see lagerone's answer). With custom delimiters you can achieve pretty close result to what you want:

```
grunt.template.addDelimiters('myDelimiters', '{{', '}}');
```

In this case your template will have to use `{{= secret }}` tags.

**#2**. Another option is that you can always write you own simple task. In your case it can look like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    myTask: {
        options: {
            data: {
                secret: 'ABC'
            },
            src:  'index.html',
            dest: 'index.output.html'
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('myTask', function() {

    var options = this.options(),
        template = grunt.file.read(options.src);

    var content = template.replace(/\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}/g, function(a, b) {
        return typeof options.data[b] !== undefined ? options.data[b] : '';
    });

    grunt.file.write(options.dest, content);
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['myTask']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [grunt-include-replace](https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace) in the past. Is easy to use. In your gruntfile you will create a task similar to this one (Example taken from official github repo):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  includereplace: {
    your_target: {
      options: {
      // Task-specific options go here.
      },
  // Files to perform replacements and includes with
  src: '*.html',
  // Destination directory to copy files to
      dest: 'dist/'
    }
  }
})
```